# How can I get the trained model from xgboost CV?

Tags: python, xgboost

I am running the following code:

```
params = {"objective":"reg:squarederror",'colsample_bytree': 0.3,'learning_rate': 0.15,
                'max_depth': 5, 'alpha': 15}

data_dmatrix = xgb.DMatrix(data=X_train,label=y_train)
cv_results = xgb.cv(dtrain=data_dmatrix, params=params, nfold=3,
                    num_boost_round=50, early_stopping_rounds=10, 
                    metrics="rmse", as_pandas=True, seed=0)
```

The result looks great and I would like to test the best model from the cross validation with my data I held back.
But how can I get the model?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unlike, say, scikit-learn [GridSearchCV](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html), which returns a model (optionally refitted with the whole data if called with `refit=True`), `xgb.cv` does **not** return any model, only the evaluation history; from the [docs](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#xgboost.cv):

> Returns evaluation history

In this sense, it is similar to scikit-learn's [`cross_validate`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_validate.html), which also does not return any model - only the metrics.

So, provided that you are happy with the CV results and you want to proceed to fit the model with all the data, you must do it separately:

```
bst = xgb.train(dtrain=data_dmatrix, params=params, num_boost_round=50)
```

Comment: How does xgb.train compare with what I see in examples which is `xg_cls = xgb.XGBClassifier()` and then `xg_cls.fit(...)`?  I'm having trouble understanding what the `cv` method is using compared to `XGBClassifier` or `XGBRegressor`?

Answer (score 7):

XGBoost API provides the [callbacks mechanism](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/callbacks.html). Callbacks allow you to call custom function before and after every epoch, before and after training.

Since you need get final models after cv, we can define such callback:

```py
class SaveBestModel(xgb.callback.TrainingCallback):
    def __init__(self, cvboosters):
        self._cvboosters = cvboosters
    
    def after_training(self, model):
        self._cvboosters[:] = [cvpack.bst for cvpack in model.cvfolds]
        return model
```

In case of `xgb.cv` the argument `model` in method `after_training` is an instance of [`xgb.training._PackedBooster`](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/python-package/xgboost/training.py#L200). Now we should pass callback to `xgb.cv`.

```py
cvboosters = []

cv_results = xgb.cv(dtrain=data_dmatrix, params=params, nfold=3,
                    num_boost_round=50, early_stopping_rounds=10, 
                    metrics="rmse", as_pandas=True, seed=0,
                    callbacks=[SaveBestModel(cvboosters), ])
```

Your models will be saved in `cvboosters`.

Comment: Not sure if it works xgb.cv(dtrain=data_dmatrix, params=params, nfold=3,
                    num_boost_round=50, early_stopping_rounds=10, 
                    metrics="rmse", as_pandas=True, seed=0,
                    callbacks=[SaveBestModel(cvboosters), ]) in your code is there a validation dataset? without a validation dataset, how will the model early stop?

Comment: @HC_2016 You should recap, how cross validation works. It doesn't need extra validation dataset, because it splits all passed data by folds.